# Is Rapportive deprecated, discontinued?

Tags: gmail, rapportive

Rapportive has made itself an essential Chrome extension in my professional toolbox. Last February, the company was acquired by LinkedIn. Nevertheless the extension continued to function as it was designed.

Today, that no longer seems to be the case. Although Rapportive works in my Google Apps mail account, it no longer seems to work in my regular Gmail account. Instead of Rapportive's right panel, I get info provided by Google (Sender, "Add to circles," etc.), plus ads.

Additionally, although it is accessible [via direct link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rapportive/hihakjfhbmlmjdnnhegiciffjplmdhin/related), Rapportive no longer appears searchable in the [Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps).

Has the app been discontinued?

Comment: Still works for me in my regular Gmail account. (Chrome+Win7)

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps Google people widget took over. Try reinstalling the extension?

Comment: They were [acquired by LinkedIn](http://blog.rapportive.com/rapportive-acquired-by-linkedin). It wouldn't surprise me if there's some interference there. Or maybe it's just neglected; the blog hasn't been updated for two years.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but deleting the extension from my Chrome extension manager and reinstalling via the direct link seemed to do the trick.